Redirection and rendering issue with Symfony
I have a route, which is accessed as a return from a webhook, the function of this route is to take what comes from the webhook and then redirect it to another page.
I'm using ngrock to receive the webhook.
From what I understand, when inspecting the return via ngrock, the symfony page responsible for the redirect is displayed, but nothing happens, the page does not change.
I will explain the methods here in case anyone can help.
    #[Route('/webhook-handler', name: 'app_webhook_handler', methods: ['POST'])]
    public function pixPaymentConfirmation(Request $request): Response
    {
        $data = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);

        if ($data['data']['id']) {
            return $this->redirectToRoute('smart_app_render_page_route');
        }

        return new Response('Condition not satisfied', Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
    }

    #[Route('/render-page', name: 'app_render_page_route', methods: ['GET'])]
    public function renderPage(): Response
    {
        return $this->render('smart_closet/start/index.html.twig');
    }

**Explanation of how everything should work.
Remembering that this is a testing environment.
Payment form**
enter image description here
As it is a testing environment, when generating the QrCode, the webhook, triggers a POST request for my route, with a successful payment status.
At this point you should redirect to the application's main page (the problem is here).
**ngrok return
**
enter image description here
In web applications is common to use the 301 HTTP status code to make permanent redirections and the 302 code to make temporary redirections. However
The problem is that it doesn't reload the main page.
Well, that's my challenge, if anyone could help I would appreciate it.
 #[Route('/webhook-handler', name: 'app_webhook_handler', methods: ['POST'])]
    public function pixPaymentConfirmation(Request $request): Response
    {
        $data = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);

        if ($data['data']['id']) {
            return $this->redirectToRoute('smart_app_render_page_route');
        }

        return new Response('Condition not satisfied', Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
    }

    #[Route('/render-page', name: 'app_render_page_route', methods: ['GET'])]
    public function renderPage(): Response
    {
        return $this->render('smart_closet/start/index.html.twig');
    }


If it is a webhook, the other server just make a POST request with the data, ususally it will not follow a redirection. That's the way it works. I do not understand what exactly you're trying to do, but anyway for a webhook if you want you can call another controller if necessary.

I'm doing exactly what you said, I'm receiving a request from a webhook via POST, and I'm getting the result and validating it. If true, I call another controller with a method that renders what I need, but that rendering doesn't work.

No, "redirectToRoute" is a shortcut for return new RedirectResponse($this->generateUrl('smart_app_render_page_route')). It is not the same as forwarding to another controller. https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/forwarding.html

I don't want to simply redirect to a controller, that was an attempt. What I really want is to call another form.
Example:
Webhook, makes the request for my route, at that moment I receive the response and check if the id is filled in, if so, then I need to redirect it to another form.
That's what's not working, I can't render the other form.

As said by Frédéric Clausset in its comment, the server calling your webhook may not, and should not for security and performance concerns, follow redirect responses.
You should forward the request to your other controller:
    #[Route('/webhook-handler', name: 'app_webhook_handler', methods: ['POST'])]
    public function pixPaymentConfirmation(Request $request): Response
    {
        $data = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);

        if ($data['data']['id']) {
            return $this->forward([$this, 'renderPage']);
        }

        return new Response('Condition not satisfied', Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
    }

See How to Forward Requests to another Controller
for more information.

I don't want to simply redirect to a controller, that was an attempt. What I really want is to call another form.
Example:
Webhook, makes the request for my route, at that moment I receive the response and check if the id is filled in, if so, then I need to redirect it to another form.
That's what's not working, I can't render the other form.

I think there is misunderstanding. A webhook is an HTTP-based callback function that allows lightweight, event-driven communication between 2 application programming interfaces (APIs). It does not make sense to redirect a webhook to a form.
When a user goes to a payment interface and makes the payment. Ususally two things happen. 1)  the user is redirected to your site.  2) the payment interface calls one of your webhook to inform you that a payment has been made.  It seems you're talking about the first one here.  Our response and comment was about the second one.
